# Are the control characters any useful nowadays?

Tags: unicode

*I am sorry if the control characters are actually super useful nowadays; I am not an electrician.*

I am studying Unicode characters. More specifically, I am learning when and how to use them. But the control codepoints keep bugging me.

#### What are even contr...?

By "Control characters", I mean the [set of valid ASCII/Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) which do not render anything, but instead were (*or are*) used to control the host device.

## So what?

Indeed, some control characters, like the Linefeed (LF) and Tab (HT) are still used today commonly for organizing text, but what about the others? Where can I use the Device Control 3 (DC3)? Can I even use the Negative Acknowledgment (NAK)?

It would be great if someone can write a detailed usage definition for each control character (If it *is* useful nowadays).

Thanks!

Comment: _"I am not an electrician"_ - huh? What do electricians have to do with this?

Comment: Might be better asked on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Might be not better asked there: the question is clearly about *contemporary* usage.